# How can I view files created on vagrant in finder

Tags: maven

I installed jenkins through vagrant CLI from terminal and installed maven plugin from jenkins. Maven is working fine, I am able to give the goals through CLI. Where can I view the files I created on maven on finder in MAC. Attached is the screenshot of my maven directory structure.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll can to modify your `./Vagrantfile` and set up a [Synced Folder](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html) between the guest and the host.

If you are using virtual box as your hypervisor you will need to install [Virtualbox Guest Editions](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/boxes.html#virtualbox-guest-additions).

However, if you just want to be able to transfer the files on the guest back to the host (instead of live editing the files), you can use the command

`$ vagrant scp boxname:/path/to/file ./local/location`

Comment: If files or directories on the remote machine that are not accessible by the `vagrant` user, try `$vagrant sudo-rsync`

See: https://www.typist.tech/projects/vagrant-sudo-rsync